# google sheets query with dropdowns

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

I am struggling with my query. It is only showing my header rows. I would like the choice of “staff” or “student” match column C on Responses tab and then the “1.) 11/3/2022 for Boy’s Basketball” match Column E on Response tab. When those two conditions are selected I want to see just the data matching staff and that event. I’m at a loss of how to get this to work.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1icO6CI_xM75jH8PSFSMFrWYZqnBLEIEBNZZI-oDAm_s/edit

Comment: Your sheet is private. Give permission to edit it or make a demo file.

Comment: It should be shareable now.  Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: What about `FILTER()` function like `=FILTER(RESPONSES!A:E,RESPONSES!C:C=A1,RESPONSES!E:E=B1)`, Query actually didn't determine datatype of E column.

Comment: Copy of [Query meeting 2 conditions](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/166654/269219).

Comment: Your question can be greatly improved if you add a table to the question. [Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) are a better alternative than spreadsheets to show your data structure.  If you share spreadsheets, make sure to also add images of your sheet to avoid closure of your question, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455/) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Answer (score 1):

Your formula attempt is:

`=query('Form Responses 3'!1:103,"SELECT D,F WHERE C = '"&A1&"' and F = '"&B1&"'")`

That fails because your search keys include an apostrophe `'`.

The easiest solution is probably to express the same through `filter()`, like this:

```
=filter( 
  { 'Form Responses 3'!D2:D, 'Form Responses 3'!F2:F }, 
  'Form Responses 3'!C2:C = A1, 
  'Form Responses 3'!F2:F = B1 
)
```

See your [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1icO6CI_xM75jH8PSFSMFrWYZqnBLEIEBNZZI-oDAm_s/edit#gid=883180294).